# CircleCI not picking up environment variable defined in run step?

Tags: python, django, yaml, circleci

I'm trying to run CircleCI tests for a Django project in which the `manage.py` determines the version of `settings.py` to apply (`development.py`, `staging.py`, or `production.py`) from an environment variable, `ENV_ROLE`. Previously, `ENV_ROLE` was set to default to `development` if not defined, but I'm in the process of changing it so that Django instead throws an `ImproperlyConfigured` error if it is not defined.

In order to make the tests pass, I need to define the `ENV_ROLE` environment variable in our CircleCI test environment. Following https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-step, I've added the following to the `run` step:

```
      - run:
          environment:
            ENV_ROLE: development
```

However, I am still getting this error from CircleCI:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
cd lucy-web
source venv/bin/activate
python manage.py compilescss --verbosity 0
python manage.py collectstatic --clear --no-input --verbosity 0
flake8
python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/env.py", line 5, in <module>
    ENV_ROLE = os.environ['ENV_ROLE']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'ENV_ROLE'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from env import ENV_ROLE
  File "/root/lucy/lucy_web/lucy-web/env.py", line 8, in <module>
    "No 'ENV_ROLE' environment variable is defined. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: No 'ENV_ROLE' environment variable is defined. Please define it as 'development', 'staging', or 'production'.
Exited with code 1
```

Here is the complete `.circleci/config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/lucy/lucy_web/
    docker:
      - image: python:3.6.5
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: ...
      - image: jannkleen/docker-postgres-gis-hstore
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: ...
          POSTGRES_DB: ...
      - image: redis:4.0.9-alpine
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "lucy-web/requirements.txt" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Python deps in a venv
          command: |
            cd lucy-web
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      - save_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "lucy-web/requirements.txt" }}
          paths:
            - "venv"
      - run:
          environment:
            ENV_ROLE: development
          command: |
            cd lucy-web
            source venv/bin/activate
            python manage.py compilescss --verbosity 0
            python manage.py collectstatic --clear --no-input --verbosity 0
            flake8
            python manage.py test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: tr1
      - store_test_results:
          path: test-reports/
  app_test:
    working_directory: ~/lucy/lucy_app
    docker:
      - image: node:8
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          command: |
            cd lucy-app
            yarn install
            yarn lint
            yarn jest
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - app_test
```

The Django project has a modified `manage.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set environment variables from .env file
    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

    # Determine which settings to apply (development, staging, or production)
    from env import ENV_ROLE
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", f"lucy.settings.{ENV_ROLE}")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django  # noqa: F401
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

where `env.py` checks whether the `ENV_ROLE` environment variable is defined and throws an `ImproperlyConfigured` error otherwise:

```
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

try:
    ENV_ROLE = os.environ['ENV_ROLE']
except KeyError:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        "No 'ENV_ROLE' environment variable is defined. "
        "Please define it as 'development', 'staging', or 'production'.")
```

I don't understand why CircleCI is not 'picking up' the `ENV_ROLE` environment variable? Is there something wrong with my syntax or understanding of the documentation?

Comment: Can you try setting the variable at the job level instead of the step level?

Comment: I would try adding `env` as the first line in the command to print out the full environment, and see if `ENV_ROLE` is being set.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using circleCI + GAE; the variables I thought I was setting in .circleCI/config.yml never actually make it to the app because the build process run by GAE wasn't transferring them in. Instead I needed to:

- make multiple app.yaml files (in my case app-staging.yaml and app-prod.yaml)
- update .circleci/config.yml to use those in each command statement, like:

  command: gcloud app deploy app-staging.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the variables in the docker: section.

```
docker:
    environment:
        ENV_ROLE: development
```

This should spin up your container with the environment var. I had to test where to insert my VARs for a few builds before they were accessible by my container.

If you can see either of these vars at the point you need the ENV_ROLE then you might want to add your there as well.

```
environment:
          DATABASE_URL: ...
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: ...
          POSTGRES_DB: ...
```